# Call helper method from custom view Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, helper

In ApplicationHelper, I have method called finTime.

```
def finTime(time)
end
```

In delayed_job I have render_to_string function

```
class ExportJob < Struct.new(:time1,:time2, :survey_id)
   def perform
       ac = ActionController::Base.new()
   html = ac.render_to_string(:template => "pages/exportPdf.html.erb",:layout =>    "layouts/exportPdf",:formats => :html
   end
end
```

In exportPdf.html.erb I call the function finTime

```
<%= finTime(f.created_at) %>
```

I got the error: "ActionView::Template:Error: undefined method 'finTime' for #<#Class:0x6db8eb0>: 0x8321928>"

So I want to ask how I can call finTime method from exportPdf.html.erb in this case. I tried to use include and helper but it does not work.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a lot of information to go on here, but one possibility could be that in your definition there are no arguments - it's just `finTime`

but in the call you give an argument of `f.created_at` - maybe that's causing the error, maybe not.  what is the full error?

related, the general practice for method names is snake case, so `finTime` should be `fin_time`.

**edit**: Without seeing more of your code it's still difficult, for example

```
<%= finTime(f.created_at) %>
```

Is that what it's in your code?  `finTime()` is a method, so it has to be called on a model - `model.finTime(time)`

there's also an end parenthesis missing from this line:

```
html = ac.render_to_string(:template => "pages/exportPdf.html.erb",:layout =>    "layouts/exportPdf",:formats => :html
```

if both of those things are only problems in your question, and not in your code, try replacing `finTime()` with [`inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-inspect) or [`methods`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-methods) in your partial and see what happens.  If there's still an error, you'll know you have to look elsewhere, and if not you'll get some information that might help you sort out the trouble.  Good luck!

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the finTime function, it has argument. I do not think snake case is the problem because that function works. The problem is that the function is not defined (cannot call that helper function
ActionView::Template:Error: undefined  method 'finTime' for #<#Class:0x6db8eb0>: 0x8321928>

Comment: ah, sorry, snake case is definitely not an issue with it working or not, just wanted to say that it's convention to use it for methods.  will update answer

Comment: Thanks you for your help. I could call finTime by using PagesController.new.finTime now :)

Comment: glad it helped!  could you checkmark the answer so it's out of the 'unanswered' queue?